# ¿Cómo importo/configuro un proyecto, trabajado en laravel, en LAMP (localhost) - Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: php, laravel, mvc, ubuntu, lampp

Me han pasado un proyecto web trabajado en laravel. Al querer correrlo en el localhost de Ubuntu (var/www/html/proyecto) que se configuró previamente.
**Me bota el error: "Mcrypt PHP extension required".**

Soy novicio en Laravel; y quisiera saber a qué se debe este problema, si es configuración de un archivo solamente o estoy cometiendo un error al correrlo en el LAMP.

Nota 1: **Ya se instaló correctamente la extensión "Mcrypt" (verificado en phpinfo())**

Nota 2: El proyecto ha sido exportado de un hosting.

Nota 3: Se configuró el acceso a la base de datos en función a la credenciales del LAMP (localhost).[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que version de PHP utilizas por que la extension que mencionas fue eliminada en PHP 7.2 https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php#migration71.deprecated.ext-mcrypt entiendo que es una version antigua de laravel por que creo que solo en laravel 4 era requerida la extension mcrypt.

Answer (score 1):

en la documentación muestra las extensiones de PHP que necesita laravel para funcionar, es importante instalarlas. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation

Si estas en un debian / ubuntu, utiliza el siguiente comando

```
$ sudo apt-get install php-mcrypt
```

En caso de que te muestre un error, asegurate de haber instalado las dependencias de Mcrypt, [aquí las puedes encontrar](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-php-7-2-mcrypt-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/)

Asegurate de importar la extensión en el php.ini

Answer (score 1):

Para saber si en realidad tienes instalada la extensión mcrypt, ejecuta en la linea de comandos

```
php -m | grep mcrypt
```

Para instalar usando php 7.1 ejecute los comandos:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Puede encontrar esta respuesta en

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031921/php-mcrypt-package-missing-in-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts?newreg=026a6f80eb5b4d10ae1ba5b1da145d46

Answer (score 0):

hace tiempo atrás tuve exactamente el mismo problema, como te comentan  en otras respuestas se puede instalar dicho faltante, en mi caso no funciono y la solución fue:

**1.Purge Php**

```
sudo apt-get purge 'php*'
```

Lo que hace dicha sentencia es remover/eliminar completamente PHP.

**2.- Reinstalar PHP**

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
```

**3.- Testeando Php**

```
sudo nano /var/www/html/info.php
```

con esto crearemos un archivo para ver la info de php a este nuevo archivo le agregamos lo siguiente:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

**4.- Reiniciar Apache:**

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

**5.- Comprobamos la info:**
nos dirigimos al navegador y digitamos:

```
localhost/info.php
```

tras lo cual podremos ver algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te sirva y guie..!!